# How to setup a VPN network using GCP/AWS backbone network?

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-vpc

We have two offices at Paris and Hong Kong; To connect with each other, the normal way would be setup vpn server on one side, and connect (VPN client) on antoher side; But the internet is not stable for such a long route. Ping is high, and packet loss rate is high, > 2%;

Could we leverage the backbone network of GCP or AWS, open two cloud instance at Paris and HK, then Paris office connects to a cloud instance at GCP/AWS Paris, and Hong Kong office connects to a cloud instance at GCP/AWS HK, and let the inter-state traffic go via Cloud backbone network; Can this setup work?

Are there some solutions, tutorials? Please recommend if there are any? Thank you in advance.

Best regards
TiisCool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it can work, and I'd expect it to work by default:

1. Create two instances, one on each side.
2. Create a site-to-site VPN between both instances. It depends on provider:

   - Note that both AWS and GCP want you to use their built-in networking functionality – e.g. AWS only guarantees that cross-region traffic will use its backbone [if you use](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/) "Inter-Region VPC peering" (as mentioned in their FAQ), and the same goes [for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) as well.
   - Some providers don't have "VPC" features but nevertheless have a backbone network, e.g. both [Linode](https://blog.linode.com/2017/06/27/linode-network-backbone/) and [Digital Ocean](https://blog.digitalocean.com/whats-new-with-the-digitalocean-network/) simply send *all* cross-region traffic through their own backbone. In this case, you need to set up traditional site-to-site VPN software (IPsec, Wireguard, OpenVPN, whatever).
3. Create a VPN between each office and its "local" GCP/AWS instance. (Ideally also site-to-site but it doesn't really matter.)
4. Edit your cross-region VPN's routing table to allow both instances to reach the opposite side's office subnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for step 3, is there any requiremnts for subnet range of VPN at each side? I am using openvpn to build local office to cloud instance vpn; If Paris office PC get a VPN IP 192.168.5.X, and HK office PC get a VPN IP 192.168.6.X; how could they talk to each other? I think I need build routing tables in this case as you mentioned in Step 4, right?

Comment: Yes – each subnet needs a different range, and different subnets talk to each other through routers by use of routing tables. (That's how the entire Internet works, really)